# Symfony [Semantical Error] 'id' is not defined

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, dql

your learning Symfony neighbor here,

I am calling a method from my controller through Ajax on a select change.
I manage to get the data I send to the controller, but I'm struggling as I try to make a Select with the data I get, for some reason, no matter the existing column I decide to return, I get a "*specifiedColumn* is not defined" and I can't figure out why.

Here's my method :

```
public function getPricesAction(Request $request)
{

            $first = $request->request->get('first');
            $final = $request->request->get('final');

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    //not too sure about stacking 2 setParameter here, guess there's a better way. But even if I just use one parameter, I still get the same error 'id is not defined'.
            $getPrice = $em->createQuery('SELECT id FROM CarsBundle:Travel t WHERE t.first = :tst and t.final = :tfi')->setParameter('tre', $first)->setParameter('tra', $final);
            $result = $getPrice->getResult();

            return new JsonResponse($result);

}
```

I am using Symfony 3.3

thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$getPrice = $em->createQuery('SELECT id FROM CarsBundle:Travel t WHERE t.first = :tst and t.final = :tfi')->setParameter('tre', $first)->setParameter('tra', $final);
```

Should be:

```
$getPrice = $em->createQuery('SELECT id FROM CarsBundle:Travel t WHERE t.first = :tst and t.final = :tfi')->setParameter('tst', $first)->setParameter('tfi', $final);
```

You got the wrong parameter name

Comment: Oh boy... thanks a lot ! also figured it should be `SELECT t.id`, it works now !